# Image mean and kurtosis - Matlab

Tags: matlab

Why is the a diffrence in the results of image mean and kurtosis using the matrix or the histogram? what is the correct way?

Code:

```
rgbImg = imread('peppers.png');
grayImg = rgb2gray(rgbImg);
imgHisto=imhist(grayImg);
meanGrayImg = mean(grayImg(:));
meanImgHisto = mean(imgHisto);
kurtosisGrayImg = kurtosis(grayImg(:));
kurtosisImgHisto = kurtosis(imgHisto);
```

Comment: Computing the mean of the image gray levels or computing the mean of the number of pixels in each histogram bin are two totally different things, and cannot be compared. You can compute the image mean through its histogram, but not the way you do it here. — All the dame comments apply to kurtosis.

Comment: So the correct way is mean(grayImg(:))?

Comment: Of those two, yes.